# Spring Boot 2.0 (spring-session-core-2.0.2)で、変更されたSession関連クラスのリプレース方法について

Tags: spring-boot, session

spring-session-core-2.0.2 で、旧バージョンに存在していた以下のソースが
無くなっていますが、これらのソースに替わる代替ソース、
及びリプレース実装方法が不明ですので、
アドバイス・ご指導いただければ幸いです。

・org.springframework.session.web.http.HttpSessionStrategy.java
・org.springframework.session.ExpiringSession.java

よろしくお願いいたします。

＜in English＞
In spring - session - core - 2.0.2, the following sources that existed in the previous version
Although lost, alternative sources to replace these sources,
Since the replacement mounting method is unknown,
I would be pleased if you could give me advice and guidance.

· Org.springframework.session.web.http.HttpSessionStrategy.java
· Org.springframework.session.ExpiringSession.java

Thank you.

【追記】

＞TAKUMA様
ご回答いただきありがとうございます。
確認・参考にさせていただき、対応可否結果は後日追記させていただきます。

また、質問対象から、以下が漏れておりましたので、
追記させてください。

・org.springframework.session.SessionRepository.java

旧バージョンに存在していた、getSessionメソッドが同様に無くなっておりまして、
代替ソース・方法がないか探したものの不明でしたので、
もし何か手がかりとなる情報お持ちでしたら、是非ご教授いただけないでしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

コミット履歴を見ると、`HttpSessionStrategy`は`HttpSessionIdResolver`にリネームしたっぽいですね。

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-session/commit/6f05c84aa7c1f7c4efcf2c0d3c20709a79b0785f

`ExpiringSession`は`Session`クラスの中にメソッドを移行したようです。

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-session/commit/4cf26d9c361f3f5d70dbf06dbb0826f8d2735f31

なので、基本的に以下のように変更すればOKですかね。

`org.springframework.session.web.http.HttpSessionStrategy` → `org.springframework.session.web.http.HttpSessionIdResolver`
`org.springframework.session.ExpiringSession` → `org.springframework.session.Session`

**追記**

追加の質問についてですが、以下のコミットで`getSession`は`findById`にメソッド名が変わっています。

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-session/commit/0127ef9f9bf4a4a41f83092022e1ab81e61a86db#diff-c0f7eef08416729ad4291ae9a7e6e6e3

Comment: ＞TAKUMA様
ご回答いただきありがとうございます。
確認・参考にさせていただき、対応可否結果は後日追記させていただきます。 また、質問対象から、以下が漏れておりましたので、
追記させてください。 ・org.springframework.session.SessionRepository.java 旧バージョンに存在していた、getSessionメソッドが同様に無くなっておりまして、
代替ソース・方法がないか探したものの不明でしたので、
もし何か手がかりとなる情報お持ちでしたら、是非ご教授いただけないでしょうか？